# What Does "Not My will but yours be done" mean?

Tags: will-of-god

I need for things in about the bible to line up with our lives down here like when receiving prayer we should get what we ask for. Right now it's all negative coming from the belligerent acting warfare waging war coming up against my life and personal freedoms. When who the son sets free is free indeed, and need His mercies.

Comment: Welcome! Jesus didn't get always what he asked for - even he had to submit his will to his Father and God.

Comment: This question is answerable in the general case, but if you are looking for personal advice we strongly recommend you get it in person from a Christian you trust and who knows you, not from strangers on the internet like us.

Answer (score 2):

It means that people who profess to be Christians must submit their will, or their desires, to the will of God, just as Jesus did.  Jesus said:

> Whoever does God’s will is my brother and sister and mother (Mark 3:35).

God’s will is knowable and provable:

> Do not conform any longer to the pattern of this world, but be transformed by the renewing of your mind. Then you will be able to test and approve what God’s will is — His good, pleasing and perfect will (Romans12:2).

God's will is about us pleasing God and serving Him:

> Teach me to do your will, for you are my God! Let your good Spirit lead me (Psalm 143:10).

> Delight yourself in the LORD and He will give you the desires of your heart (Psalm 37:4).

It’s true that Jesus said, “If you believe, you will receive whatever you ask for in prayer” (Matthew 21:22). But, even in that statement, we have one condition to prayer: faith.

It isn't about what you think you need, or getting what you ask for.  It isn't about what you perceive to be your "personal freedoms."  It's about following Jesus, and taking up your cross.  It's about humility and serving others, just as Jesus did.

Answer (score 2):

The quote is from the Bible, [Luke Chapter 22 verses 41-42.](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2022&version=NKJV). There are similar passages in the other Gospels.

> And He was withdrawn from them about a stone’s throw, and He knelt down and prayed, saying, “Father, if it is Your will, take this cup away from Me; nevertheless not My will, but Yours, be done.”

This is from a time in Jesus' life when he is about to die a horrible and painful death, to redeem Mankind from their sins. He is praying to God. The meaning is "Father, I don't want to die, but if it is your will I will do it".

The general understanding is that this shows Jesus' perfect submission to his Father's will rather than his own, and also sets an example for Christians to follow in putting God's will before theirs.

Comment: How would you explain, 'I and the Father are one', and Jesus having his own will?

Comment: @user47952 That's a separate question, though I think one that's been answered. Please look for questions that answer that, and if you really don't find one use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score -1):

This is one verse that shows Jesus having another will to his Father/God.

> "Father, if you are willing, take this cup from me; yet **not my will**, but yours be done."

> John 12:49 ‘I have not **spoken on My own**, but the Father who sent Me has commanded Me what to say and how to say it’

> John 6:38 ‘For I have come down from heaven, not **to do My own will**, but the will of Him who sent Me.’

Plainly showing that Jesus cannot be God as in, 'the Father and I are one', by having a *differing* will.

Indeed Jesus was made just like us - in every way. It doesn't say in many ways or most ways - it says every way, in every respect.

> Therefore, He had to be made like His brethren in all things Heb 2:17

Jesus was able to be tempted - yes, even sin - otherwise the temptation would be pointless or just for show.

> For we do not have a high priest who is unable to empathize with our weaknesses, but we have one who has been tempted in every way, just as we are--yet he did not sin. Heb 4:15

As God cannot be tempted, this presents a problem.

thus, **what does it mean, "not my will but yours be done"?**

Jesus, the man, has been 'made perfect' for the mission of being a sinless sacrifice for all men. Heb 5:9 Even though he was born holy, he wasn't yet suitable for such a purpose.

His sacrifice was more than just to cover our sin - it was to also defeat death - the very evil that causes death- the devil. He could only do this as the second Adam - a *man* without sin, and tested to breaking point without letting self-centred thinking get the better of him. If he was God, this would be a farce.

As Jesus has won the final victory over sin and death, we too share in his win in our lives. He and the Father dwelling in us in spirit grant us the heart and will to submit our will to God.

This is still our choice, but is *only* made possible by God

> for it is God who works in you, both to will and to work for his good pleasure. Phil 2:13